# Emacs shell-mode display is too wide after splitting window

Tags: emacs

If I run `M-x shell` in emacs to get a terminal, it knows where to wrap lines automatically. For example, the output of `ls` is formatted into columns that fit the window properly.

My problem is if I then split the window vertically with `C-x 3`, shell-mode still thinks the window fills the whole frame. The result is ugly wrapping of command output. Is there a way to let shell-mode know it has to update the screen width?

EDIT:

Using HN's answer below, I came up with this fix:

```
(defun my-resize-window ()
  "Reset the COLUMNS environment variable to the current width of the window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
        (str (format "export COLUMNS=%s" (window-width))))
    (funcall comint-input-sender proc str)))

(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key "\C-cw" 'my-resize-window))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but COLUMNS isn't the way to do this. Here is an excerpt from my .emacs:

```
(defun comint-fix-window-size ()
  "Change process window size."
  (when (derived-mode-p 'comint-mode)
    (set-process-window-size (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
                         (window-height)
                         (window-width))))

(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  ;; add this hook as buffer local, so it runs once per window.
  (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'comint-fix-window-size nil t))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

Unlike exporting COLUMNS each time, this method doesn't require you to be in
bash at the moment and it doesn't spam your session with blank prompts. This
code should probably be in comint itself, maybe I will file a bug report.

EDIT: If you modify `window-configuration-change-hook` in a buffer-local-way
the hook runs once per window, as opposed once per frame.

Comment: This is a really useful fix. Please do submit as a bug report!

Comment: Thanks for the useful function, however it will cause problems when the process is nil, so I added a nil check before set process window size - [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20015336/554279)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly improved resize function from @Christopher Monsanto's answer. The original one will cause a problem due to nil process. (e.g `exit` in shell-mode)

```
(defun comint-fix-window-size ()
  "Change process window size."
  (when (derived-mode-p 'comint-mode)
    (let ((process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
      (unless (eq nil process)
        (set-process-window-size process (window-height) (window-width))))))
```

Comment: (when process is more idiomatic than (unless (eq nil process)

Answer (score 2):

This display is dictated by the COLUMNS environment variable. In my setup COLUMNS has a value of 202, after a vertical split ls displays correctly on shell-mode if I set columns to 80 via

```
export COLUMNS=80
```

There must be a way to code this up but I don't have enough elisp-fu to do that. If you'd rather avoid the hassle multi-term manages this automagically.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `eshell`; it doesn't have this problem.